# check a checkbox when other specific checkbox is checked is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form that has some questions (email, phone number) and then the user can select if that field should be included for the registration types that exist for a conference (in this case RT 001 and RT 002) and also if that field should be mandatory or not for each registration type. (Layout: https://ibb.co/kftnPc)

I have this code below to when the input with "mandatorycheckbox" class is checked that the input with "rtypecheckbox" be also checked.  Because for sure if the field is mandatory for a specific registration type it needs to be included in the registration form for that specific registration type:

```
 $(function() {
      $('.mandatorycheckbox').change(function() {
       if (this.checked)
          $('.rtypecheckbox').prop('checked', true);
      });
});
```

**Issue:**

The issue is that when some "mandatory for RT 001" or "mandatory for RT 002" inputs are checked all "Include for registration type..." are checked.

But I just want that for example, if the checkbox "mandatory for RT 001" is checked check the "Include for registration type RT 001" and not check all inputs "Include for registration type...".

Do you know how to do that?

Html (in this case there are 2 questions for the conference):

```
    <form method="post" class="clearfix"
          action="{{route('questions.update', ['conf_id' => $conf->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Info</th>
      <th scope="col">Include for registration type</th>
      <th scope="col">Mandatory Field</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>whats your phone number?</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input autocomplete="off" name="question[1][rtypes][]" class="form-check-input rtypecheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" id="1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            include for registration type "general"
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input autocomplete="off" name="question[1][rtypes][]" class="form-check-input rtypecheckbox" type="checkbox" value="2" id="2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            include for registration "plus"
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input autocomplete="off"  name="question[1][mandatories][]"
                 class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" id="1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            for the registration type "general"
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input autocomplete="off"  name="question[1][mandatories][]"
                 class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="2" id="2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            for the registration type "plus"
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Whats your email?</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input autocomplete="off" name="question[2][rtypes][]" class="form-check-input rtypecheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" id="1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
             include for registration "general"
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input autocomplete="off" name="question[2][rtypes][]" class="form-check-input rtypecheckbox" type="checkbox" value="2" id="2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
             include for registration "plus"
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input autocomplete="off"  name="question[2][mandatories][]"
                 class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="1" id="1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            for the registration type "geral"
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input autocomplete="off"  name="question[2][mandatories][]"
                 class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="2" id="2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            for the registration type "plus"
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please included the parsed HTML. See: [*MCVE*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I update the question with the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your different checkboxes (for "general" and "plus" registration types) additional classes e.g. `general` and `plus`. Likewise you would give the mandatory checkboxes the same additional classes. e.g. based on your fiddle:

```
  <tr>
    <td>whats your phone number?</td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input autocomplete="off" name="question[1][rtypes][]" class="form-check-input rtypecheckbox general" type="checkbox" value="1" id="1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
          include for registration type "general"
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input autocomplete="off" name="question[1][rtypes][]" class="form-check-input rtypecheckbox plus" type="checkbox" value="2" id="2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
          include for registration "plus"
        </label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input autocomplete="off"  name="question[1][mandatories][]"
               class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox general" type="checkbox" value="1" id="1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
          for the registration type "general"
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input autocomplete="off"  name="question[1][mandatories][]"
               class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox plus" type="checkbox" value="2" id="2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
          for the registration type "plus"
        </label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Then you could change the javascript to

```
$(function() {
      $('.mandatorycheckbox').change(function() {
       if (this.checked) {
          if ($(this).hasClass('general')
              $('.rtypecheckbox.general').prop('checked', true);
          else if ($(this).hasClass('plus')
              $('.rtypecheckbox.plus').prop('checked', true);
       }
      });
});
```

If the classes have to be dynamic, you could try something like

```
var questionClasses = ['general', 'plus', 'xyz', ...];

$(function() {
      $('.mandatorycheckbox').change(function() {
       if (this.checked) {
          for (var i = 0; i < questionClasses.length; i++) {
              if ($(this).hasClass(questionClasses[i])
                  $('.rtypecheckbox.' + questionClasses[i]).prop('checked', true);
              }
       }
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that "general" and "plus" are dynamic, they can be anything, it can be more than 1 word. Do you know how to handle that?

Comment: See my edit. If you can auto-generate the questionClasses variable that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks but it's not working, when some checkbox is checked no checkbox is checked. In source code it appears: var questionClasses = ["geral","plus"].

Comment: Hi John, you didn't add the "general" and "plus" classes to the checkbox inputs. When you add them in the fiddle it works for me. Unfortunately I can't update the fiddle so I'll copy a snippet of the code into my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I added, but it still not works: https://jsfiddle.net/qy3v9j3m/5/

Comment: Hi John, it looks like you didn't also add the classes to the mandatory checkbox inputs?

Comment: That fiddle still has no classes on the mandatory checkboxes: <input autocomplete="off"  name="question[2][mandatories][]"                    class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="2" id="2"> should have class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox general" or class="form-check-input mandatorycheckbox plus"

Answer (score 0):

You should use id selector instead of class selector, and make every checkbox with a unique id. Example like this:

```
$(function() {
      $('.mandatorycheckbox').change(function() {
       if (this.checked)
          $('#id1').prop('checked', true);
          $('#id2').prop('checked', true);
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the id is being used for another thing in the backend so it seems that its necessary to use classes.

Comment: It's able to use another id in the html, I don't understand why you use the same id in the backend